# How to correctly pass the MainActivity object to the fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I can't figure out why the application is displaying null when the username (from user object) should be displayed.
When I display through toasts in the MainActivity, everything is displayed correctly.

Fragment:

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

```
companion object{
    fun getNewInstance(user: User) : HomeFragment {
        val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
        homeFragment.arguments?.putSerializable("user", user)
        return homeFragment
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val user = arguments?.getSerializable("user") as? User
    binding.textHome.text = user?.name.toString()
    return binding.root
}
```

}

and MainActivity:

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
@SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val db = DataBaseController(this, null)
    val databaseExists = db.doesDatabaseExist(this, "users")

    if (!databaseExists) {
    val registration = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(registration)
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var userName = SharedPreferencesHelper(this).getUserName()
    var user = db.getUserByName(userName)

    Toast.makeText(this, "${user!!.name} ${user!!.level} hello!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Toast.makeText(this, user.name.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    val homeFragment = HomeFragment.getNewInstance(user)

    val dashboardFragment: Fragment = DashboardFragment()

    val notificationsFragment: Fragment = NotificationsFragment()
    
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    
    val navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)!!)
    
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home,
            R.id.navigation_dashboard,
            R.id.navigation_notifications
        )
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

}

I tried to pass the argument through the bundle, but it didn’t get better, I couldn’t figure it out

Comment: did you try using parcelable instead of serializable ?

Comment: yes i tried but the result is the same  :^(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```kotlin
val homeFragment = HomeFragment.getNewInstance(user)
```

Here, you create an instance of `HomeFragment` and pass the `User` to it. However, you then do absolutely nothing with that object. It is unused. There are no references to that variable.

Hence, if you are seeing a `HomeFragment` instance on the screen, that is coming from somewhere else, and it does not have access to the `User`.

Most likely, `HomeFragment` should have its own viewmodel, and that viewmodel should retrieve the  `User` from the database (preferably on a background thread, such as by using coroutines).

Comment: your solution works, however... isn't there a better solution than opening the database from fragments every time? the data that is stored in the user object will change (for example, the level)

Comment: @tyomnayark: Often times, if the data changes, you will want to update the database to match. Beyond that, caching usually is performed in a repository layer that sits between the viewmodel and the database. Modern Android app architecture is covered in many books and courses. I cover it in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-arch-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack), among other places.